# What is difference between a job and a process in Unix?

Tags: unix

What is the difference between a **job** and a **process** in Unix ? Can you please give an example ?

Answer (score 17):

Jobs are processes which are started by a shell. The shell keeps track of these in a job table. The `jobs` command shows a list of active background processes. They get a jobspec number which is not the PID of the process. Commands like `fg` use the jobspec ID.

In the spirit of [Jürgen Hötzel's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2718999):

```
find $HOME | sort &
[1] 15317
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 find $HOME | sort &
$ fg
find $HOME | sort
  C-c C-z
[1]+  Stopped                 find $HOME | sort
$ bg 1
[1]+ find $HOME | sort &
```

Try the examples yourself and look at the man pages.

Answer (score 11):

A [Process Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) can be considered as a *Job*. For example you create a background process group in shell:

```
$ find $HOME|sort &
[1] 2668
```

And you can see two processes as members of the new process group:

```
$ ps -p 2668 -o cmd,pgrp 
CMD                          PGRP
sort                         2667


$ ps -p "$(pgrep -d , -g 2667)" -o cmd,pgrp
CMD                          PGRP
find /home/juergen           2667
sort                         2667
```

You can can also kill the whole process group/job:

```
$ pkill -g 2667
```

Answer (score 6):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29:

> Processes under the influence of a job control facility are referred to as jobs.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29

Jobs are one or more processes that are grouped together as a 'job', where job is a UNIX shell concept.

Comment: can u pleasse explain with example

Comment: c/p from wikipedia is not considered to be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Jobs are one or more processes that are grouped together as a 'job', where job is a UNIX shell concept. A job consists of multiple processes running in series or parallel. while
A process is a program under execution. job is when you want to know about processes started from the current shell.

Answer (score 0):

A job consists of multiple processes running in series or parallel. A process is a program under execution.

Answer (score 0):

**job**  is when you want to know about processes started from the current shell.

**process** is when you want to know about a process running from any shell or computer.

Answer (score -1):

I think a job is a scheduled process or set of processes, a job always has the notion of schedule, otherwise we could call it a process.